# Visual Studio 2010 macro package or extension to reformat code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

Today I have been finding myself doing a lot of rearranging of code. Like converting this:

```
var assetPlacement = new AssetPlacement
    {
        Transform = worldSpaceTransform,
    };
```

to this:

```
var assetPlacement = new AssetPlacement { Transform = worldSpaceTransform, };
```

Or the reverse, when more params are added. And many more rearranging of deck chairs on the Titanic kind of thing to make OCD types like me happy.

Are there any good extensions or macros out there that provide specific types of code reformatting/refactoring like the above?

**Update:**

I am not looking for a "format my document/selection according to pretty-printing rules" and Ctrl-K whatever. Let's imagine I know my way around Visual Studio pretty well. ReSharper also does not do what I'm after.

I am looking for specific stylistic refactorings. Like changing this:

```
public string Foo { get { return _foo; } set { _foo = value; } }
```

to this:

```
public string Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set { _foo = value; }
}
```

*...on a command.* Or doing the reverse - going from the second form to the first form, on a different command. Without editing profiles and checking boxes. Easily available to go either way on a hotkey or context menu.

Visual Studio does come with a sample macro, for example, that reformats a block of text to align all the equals signs.

That's the kind of thing I'm after. Targeted stylistic reformatting.

Comment: I use ReSharper to do exactly what your updated example displays. Ctrl-E,F

Comment: Ok, but how do I do the reverse? Hmm, I must not be making myself clear. I do not want to set some settings, then reformat. I want a palette of commands that will let me say "format this way" or "format that way" without having to go mess with global options. Sort of like how R# lets you convert an auto-property to one with a backing field, and then also lets you go back. I'm looking for the same except with stylistic reformatting.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio can do some automatic formatting for you from the Edit menu under Advanced, but for more complicated code formatting I suggest [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).  A good list of what you can do is described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html).

Comment: I'm familiar with R# and use the code cleanup features often. What I'm asking about is very different. See my reply to jrummell on the question, I hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl K, ctrl + D` does this for you (Edit / Advanced / Format Document) . It's built in Visual Studio. You can adapt the rules in Options / Text Editor / C # / Formatting.

Comment: @Scott, this answer seems reasonable to me given the question you posted.  Your terse retort above is not particularly helpful for guiding people to what answer you are actually looking for.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. Did you read the phrase "Or the reverse, when more params are added."? Also updated the question to be ultra clear.